# Linear Equation in Two Variables

Tags: word-problem

Find the values of k for which the system of equation kx-y=2, 6x-2y=3 has 
1. A unique solution
2. No solution

Answer (score 1):

$$6x-2y=3$$
So
$$y=3x-3/2$$
Sub into the first equation
$$kx-3x+3/2=2$$
$$(k-3)x=1/2$$

So for all $k\ne 3$ it has a unique solution
$$x=\frac{1}{2k-6}$$

And for $k=3$, it has no solution.